# The relationship between singular values of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m\geq n$, assume singular values of $A$ are $\sigma_1\ge \sigma_2\ge \cdots\sigma_n;$ the singular values of $A+B$ are $\hat{\sigma}_1\ge \hat{\sigma}_2\ge \cdots\hat{\sigma}_n$.

Show that $|\sigma_i-\hat{\sigma}_i|\leq ||B||_2$, where $||B||_2=\sqrt{\rho(B^TB)}$.

I only know that if $A,B$ are symmetric and $\sigma_i,\hat{\sigma}_i$ are defined as eigenvalues of $A$ and $A+B$, it can be done. Here I tried to compute the eigenvalue of $(A+B)^T(A+B)$ and $A^TA$, I don't know how to deal with the term $A^TB+B^TA$.

Comment: At a quick glance, I would think that the [Courant-Fischer](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) characterization of singular values gives the nicest approach to this problem.  Also, note that
$$
\|B\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n [\sigma_i(B)]^2
$$
If I find the time and attention span, I may leave an answer to this effect, assuming it really is possible.

Comment: To clarify what I mean: we can say that
$$
[\sigma_k(A)]^2 = 
\max_{\dim(S) = k} \min_{x \in S, \|x\| = 1} x^*A^*Ax =\\
\max_{\dim(S) = k} \min_{x \in S, \|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|^2 = \\
\max_{\dim(S) = k} \min_{x \in S\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Ax\|^2}{\|x\|^2}
$$

Comment: Good, thank you a lot. I got what you mean, now I can work it out by Courant Fisher Theorem and notice $||B||_2=\max\{Bx: ||x||_2=1\}$.

Comment: Oh, my first comment was a mistake; that's $\rho$ not trace.  So yes, 
$$
\|B\|_2 = \sigma_1(B) = \max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Bx\|
$$
I'm glad you're able to figure it out!  If you do end up writing an answer, it may be helpful to future visitors if you post an answer to your own question outlining the approach you decide on.  If you end up getting stuck, feel free to ping me.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I have posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Courant Fisher Theorem: $$\sigma_i=\sqrt{\max_{\mathbb{R}^i}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i} \frac{v^TA^TAv}{v^Tv}}=\max_{\mathbb{R}^i}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i} \sqrt{\frac{||Av||_2^2}{||v||_2^2}}=\max_{\mathbb{R}^i}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} $$

$$\sigma_i=\sqrt{\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}} \frac{v^TA^TAv}{v^Tv}}=\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\sqrt{\frac{||Av||_2^2}{||v||_2^2}}=\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} $$

$$\hat{\sigma}_i=\sqrt{\max_{\mathbb{R}^i}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i} \frac{v^T(A+B)^T(A+B)v}{v^Tv}}=\max_{\mathbb{R}^i}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i} \frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}$$

$$\hat{\sigma}_i=\sqrt{\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}} \frac{v^T(A+B)^T(A+B)v}{v^Tv}}=\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}} \frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}$$

Because $$\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}\ge \min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} -\max_{v\in \mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||Bv||_2}{v^Tv}\ge\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} -||B||_2$$

$$\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}\leq \max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} +\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||Bv||_2}{v^Tv}\leq\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} +||B||_2$$
So we get $$\hat{\sigma}_i=\max_{\mathbb{R}^{i}}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}\ge \max_{\mathbb{R}^{i}}\min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^i}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} -||B||_2=\sigma_i-||B||_2$$

$$\hat{\sigma}_i=\min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||(A+B)v||_2}{||v||_2}\leq \min_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}}\frac{||Av||_2}{||v||_2} +||B||_2=\sigma_i+||B||_2$$

Then we conlude that $|\hat{\sigma}_i-\sigma_i|\leq ||B||_2,\quad i=1,2,\cdots,n.$